# In Python, how would I read in values from a file and put them in a RawArray?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a whitespace delimited list in a file, and I'm reading that into my python program with:

```
file = open(file_name, 'r')
my_list = file.read().split()
```

However, I'm trying to put these values in a `multiprocessing.RawArray` in order to allow multiple processes to access them without copying them over.

Is there a better way to do this than to just loop through the list and assign each item to a slot in the `RawArray`?

Comment: Have you tried using `multprocessing.RawArray(my_list)`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately doesn't work, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier to do this if you the manager class from multiprocessing module.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
manager = mp.Manager()
some_list = ["This is text", "This is also text"]
shared_some_list = manager.list(some_list)
```

You can then use shared_some_list in all your processes by passing it in as the argument.